# jQuery UI Dialog on dialogopen return the selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm adding some utility functions to jQuery UI dialog, and I need a way to get the selector when attaching functionality to every dialog open:

```
$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {
```

What I've found is that in the object, the selector is empty:

```
selector: "",
```

And I can't trust that every dialog will be opened by an id, so how do I find the selector on dialogopen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your open callback, event.currentTarget is a reference to the dialog.

So the following will give you the div that is being dialoged.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {
        var $div = $(event.currentTarget).find('.ui-dialog-content');

        // Do something with the div
    });

    $('#mydialog').dialog();
});
```

You can then get the id attribute or use $div.hasClass to determine which div it is.

Or you can add the selector as a data attribute to the div before dialoging it.  Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9VPg/1/).

Comment: The fiddle was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.